# Что такое обёртка в react-native?

Tags: react-native

Что такое обёртка в react-native простыми словами?

Comment: сильно выдрано из контекста

Comment: обертка компонента что это значит

Comment: вы думаете стало понятнее? скорее всего речь об обычной обертке, как и во всех других языках программирования/фреймворках. в целом -это когда ряд функциональности инкапсулируется внутри компонента, к которому вы продоставляете свой API, необходимый в конкретной ситуации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если простыми словами: React-Native работает по такому же принципу как и обычный React, однако вместо манипуляций с DOM и Virtual DOM он взаимодействует напрямую с нативными компонентами мобильной платформы через Bridge.

Наглядная схема: [image: схема работы React-Native]